# How can I have virtual copies in Lightroom default to being created at bottom of the stack

Tags: adobe, lightroom

I use Lightroom for photography, sometimes I will launch Photoshop via Edit -> In Photoshop.  Lightroom defaults to make a 16 bit TIFF copy of my raw file (fine) and opening that in Photoshop.  However, the copy is created at the top of the stack.

To me, the stack is more of a "timeline", I want the raw file first, and any edits following.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Migrating to [photo.se] at the request of the asker.

Comment: Just because you use it for photography does not make it on-topic here either.

Comment: I don't think this is technically a virtual copy. If you select edit in Photoshop, it actually creates a TIFF file as you said, and this is not a virtual copy as Lightroom would consider it. Sorry for being picky but that is my understanding.

Comment: @Itai - We've always considered LR on topic here -  I *cannot imagine* how it wouldn't be on topic here.  LR isn't the same as photoshop which can be used in a more general graphic sense - it IS for photos.

Comment: I have to agree with @rfusca here...Lightroom is pretty specific to photography, and is not a general image editing tool such as Photoshop. I don't see any scenario where questions about Lightroom would be off-topic in any capacity.

Comment: I'm still hard pressed to figure out what else people use Lightroom for, but maybe that's presumptuous of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a PSD in PS from Lightroom, it automatically stacks the PSD with the RAW file. I have confirmed that Lightroom puts the PSD first in the stack, and none of the sort orders changes this.

The trick is to unstack the PSD. Right click on the PSD, then choose unstack. If you like the PSD stacked with the original RAW, then you can restack, and adjust the slider to get the associated RAW and PSD (as well as any Virtual copies) stacked together.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to change this stacking behavior, ie.it will always stack PSD, and stack them first.

Comment: The user was creating TIFF files, but the same rules apply as PSD files.